# coordinate angle of a circle

Tags: geometry, circles, matlab

I have the following Matlab codes to generate a circle for a given radius `R`and angle $\theta$,

`m = 37;
for jj=1:m
    theta(jj,:) = (2*pi/m).*jj;
end
R = 1;
x = R*cosd(theta);
y = R*sind(theta);`

Now, suppose I want to back-calculate the angle $\theta$ from the `[x,y]`coordinate, what is the best way to do it? I have came up with the following code without success, where is the mistake?

`% Get theta
for ii=1:length(x)
   if y(ii)>=0 && x(ii)>=0 
       thetapred(ii) = 180+atand(y(ii)./x(ii));
   elseif y(ii)>0 && x(ii)<0
       thetapred(ii) = 360-atand(y(ii)./x(ii));
   elseif y(ii)<0 && x(ii)<0
       thetapred(ii) = atand(y(ii)./x(ii));
   elseif y(ii)<0 && x(ii)>0
       thetapred(ii) = 180-atand(y(ii)./x(ii));
   end
end`

Comment: Using arctan you should distinguish to main cases: x>0 and x<0. Then consider a part x=0.

Comment: Take a look here for more details https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#Converting_between_polar_and_Cartesian_coordinates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using $\arctan$ you should distinguish two main cases: $x>0$ and $x<0$ and then consider a part $x=0$.

As a simpler alternative you can calculate

- $\theta =\arccos \left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right)$ for $y\ge 0$
- $\theta =2\pi-\arccos \left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right)$ for $y< 0$

Comment: Hi @gimusi, I have tried your proposed answer, but it exactly produces the one I mentioned above.

Comment: @BeeTiau have you tried by arccos ?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I have checked and replot them. It is correct now.

Comment: Now, suppose I have a non-circular shape i.e. irregular close curve, can I use that formula to get the angle theta for a given [x,y]?

Comment: @BeeTiau Yes of course, for the general case you need only to check and avoid $x=y=0$ for which $\theta$ in undefined.

Comment: Upon closer look, can you explain this discrepancy I got for the following points? x = -0.9673    y = 0.2538   theta_ori = 72.0000  theta_pred = 106.4806

Comment: This line for example is uncorrect $if y(ii)>=0 && x(ii)>=0 thetapred(ii) = 180+atand(y(ii)./x(ii));$ just look the link I gave in the comment, there is a full defintion by arctan. And take also a look here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74489/discussion-between-beetiau-and-gimusi).

Comment: @gimusi have a look at the solution I propose.

Comment: Yes I know it, it is also mentioned in the link I gave but I’ve preferred give a solution for “standard” functions following the idea presented in the OP.

Answer (score 2):

You should use "atan2" function : it has been "invented" to avoid all this fuss by covering at once $[0,2 \pi]$; simply write :

```
 theta = atan2(y,x)
```

(Caution: $y$ before $x$).

This function, though deprived of any special mathematical status, can be found in almost all scientific software.